# ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream doesn't contain videos in the group

Tags: ios, video, alassetslibrary, alassetsgroup, photostream

The photo stream groups return a count of 0 when filtering for videos.  Here's the code to reproduce:

```
ALAssetsGroupType groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream;
ALAssetsFilter* assetTypes = [ALAssetsFilter allVideos];
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error)
{
};

ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock enumGroupsBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (group)
    {
        [group setAssetsFilter:assetTypes];
        NSString* name = [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
        NSUInteger count = group.numberOfAssets;
        NSLog(@"name: %@, count: %lu", name, (unsigned long)count);
    }
};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:enumGroupsBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

This happens with both the 'My Photo Stream' and the Shared Streams.  Note that the Photos app *does* display the videos.  Also note that filtering for photos (using [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos] above) does work.  I've reproduced this on iOS 7.1.2 and 8.1.

Has anyone else seen this or found a workaround?  Thanks!

**Update (Oct 29, 2014):** My Photo Stream does not support video, only the Shared Streams do.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4486)

> **Which photo formats does My Photo Stream support?**
>
> My Photo Stream supports JPEG, TIFF, PNG, and most RAW photo formats.
>   My Photo Stream doesn't work with video.

On my iPhone, there is no video in My Photo Stream album but only photos.

Comment: Sorry... here's the rest of my response.  Another thing to mention is that I did turn on 'iCloud Drive' (Settings -> iCloud -> iCloud Drive) and 'iCloud Photo Library (Beta)' (Settings -> iCloud -> Photos -> iCloud Photo Library (Beta)) on my iPhone that has 8.1 installed.  Maybe "...doesn't work with video" means doesn't fully support it, yet?  I wrote up a bug (18729083) and filed it with Apple to see if they'll provide additional information.  Will update this thread when I hear back.

Comment: I didn't turn on both settings, :).

Answer (score 0):

My PhotoStream never includes videos only photos. Shared Photo Streams however can contain videos.
iCloud Photo Library is not fully supported in AssetsLibrary - you may switch to PhotoKit to get full iCloud Photo Library support.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on My Photo Stream -vs- Shared Photo Streams!